# What is the most suitable way to solve a set of complex exponential equations?

Tags: complex, nonlinear

I am trying to solve set of equations which contain complex exponential terms for the analysis of a mechanism. I am rather new to Mathematica and I don't know how to proceed from here.

```
r1 = 11;
r3 = 42;
r4 = 23;
r5 = 47;
r6 = 16;
r7 = 34;
r8 = 67;

\[Theta]1 = 101*Pi/180;
\[Theta]8 = 202*Pi/180;

Subscript[r, 1] = r1*Exp[I*\[Theta]1];
Subscript[r, 2][r2_, \[Theta]2_] := r2*Exp[I*\[Theta]2];
Subscript[r, 3][\[Theta]3_] := r3*Exp[I*\[Theta]3];
Subscript[r, 4][\[Theta]4_] := r4*Exp[I*\[Theta]4];
Subscript[r, 5][\[Theta]5_] := r5*Exp[I*\[Theta]5];
Subscript[r, 6][\[Theta]6_] := r6*Exp[I*\[Theta]6];
Subscript[r, 7][\[Theta]7_] := r7*Exp[I*\[Theta]7];
Subscript[r, 8] = r8*Exp[I*\[Theta]8];

eq1 = Subscript[r, 1] + Subscript[r, 2][r2, \[Theta]2] + 
    Subscript[r, 3][\[Theta]3] + Subscript[r, 6][\[Theta]6] + 
    Subscript[r, 7][\[Theta]7] == 0;
eq2 = Subscript[r, 2][r2, \[Theta]2] + Subscript[r, 4][\[Theta]4] == 
   Subscript[r, 8];
eq3 = Subscript[r, 4][\[Theta]4] + Subscript[r, 5][\[Theta]5] == 
   Subscript[r, 3][\[Theta]3];
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It appears that you have 3 equations and many unknowns (r2 and theta2 - theta7?) so it isn't clear what you are solving for or what kind of solution you are hoping to get. As a general starting point, you might look at the documentation for the `Solve` and `Simplify` functions.

Comment: Could convert to trigs, use `TrigExpand` to get powers of "minimal" arguments, change `Sin` to `s` and similar for `Cos`, and add defining relations for the new variables (of form `c^2+s^2-1`). There are some examples of this already in MSE.